# Is there a react native router using Navigator-Experimental?

Tags: react-native, navigator

Is there a router or navigator package using the new Navigator Experimental? https://github.com/ericvicenti/navigation-rfc

Answer (score 1):

ex-navigation, react-native-router-flux and react router native all sit on top of Navigation Experimental. Depends on what kind of API you would like to use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@exponent/ex-navigation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-native